# React - Load component after useContext returns value

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, state

So I have `Dashboard` component which should display `currentUsers` info.
I keep my `currentUser` in global `context/state`.

The problem is when `Dashboard` component renders **FIRST** time `currentUser` is `null` even tho user is actually logged in. Because of that I get `null` error at line 14 or if I comment dashboard states the if statement on line 22 will happen and it will redirect me even if user is logged in.

Is there a way to await for `isLoggedInFunction` to finish and then do the logic in `Dashboard` component?

[image: Dashboard component]

In App.js

```jsx
export const CurrentUserContext = React.createContext(null); // Global Context
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null); // Global State


// Setting current user
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentUser(isLoggedIn()).catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);


// IsLoggedIn Method
export function isLoggedIn() {
     return localStorage.getItem('user') === null ? 
          null : 
          JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
}


<CurrentUserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser }}> // Provider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed both problems by doing this.

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null); // Replaced this line with next line
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(() => isLoggedIn());
```

And I removed useeffect since I don't need it anymore.

```
// Setting current user
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrentUser(isLoggedIn()).catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value for the user to avoid the first error.

In this case you can change your `Dashboard` like this:

```js
/* ... */

const {
    currentUser = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        firstName: 'first name'
    }
} = useContext(CurrentUserContext);

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(currentUser.firstName);
/* ... */

if (!currentUser.isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={'/login'}/>;
}

/* ... */
```

To solve the second problem, you need to check if your `localStorage` actually contains the `user` field after authorization.